# Sorting in xslt?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have a below code which fetches records from corresponding plmxml file and displaying records. I am displaying license_status 0 as author and 1 as consumer . What i want is to sort the license_status as author and consumer while displaying the output  ? I am displaying it as html . How can i do it ?

Thanks in advance

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>

<!--

    Filename: default_xml_template.xsl

    Default xsl template file for XML report

-->
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
           xmlns:plm="http://www.plmxml.org/Schemas/PLMXMLSchema">

<!--  Defining output as HTML -->
<xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>

<!--  Defining Global Variables 

       These are defined to avoid redundancy and use variables throughout the xsl document
--> 
<xsl:variable name="trvrootref" select="/plm:PLMXML/plm:Header/@traverseRootRefs"/>
<xsl:variable name="roid" select="substring-after($trvrootref,'#')"/>
<xsl:variable name="roe" select="/plm:PLMXML/plm:ProductView/plm:Occurrence[@id=$roid]"/>
<xsl:variable name="rprid" select="substring-after($roe/@instancedRef,'#')"/>
<xsl:variable name="root" select="/plm:PLMXML/plm:ProductRevision[@id=$rprid]"/>
<!-- Reference to the Site element and last name attribute  -->    
<xsl:variable name="site" select="/plm:PLMXML/plm:Site"/>   
<xsl:variable name="site_name" select="$site/@name"/>

<!--  The match attribute is used to associate a template with an XML element. 

       The match attribute can also be used to define a template for the entire XML document. 

       The value of the match attribute is an XPath expression (i.e. match="/" defines the whole document).
--> 
<xsl:template match="/">

<!-- 

       HTML to define the structure and presentation of the output report to be published      

-->
<html>
<head>
     <title>Global Teamcenter - Employee Information</title>


<!-- 
         Calling the createCL template , passing parameter occStr as trvrootref variable
-->
    <xsl:call-template name="createCL">
        <xsl:with-param name="occStr" select="$trvrootref"/>
    </xsl:call-template> 
    </table>
</div>
<br/>
</body>
</html>

</xsl:template>


<!-- Defining createCL template --> 
<xsl:template name="createCL">
<xsl:param name="occStr"/>
    <xsl:if test="$occStr!=''">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains($occStr,' ')">
            <xsl:variable name="occid" select="substring-before($occStr,' ')"/>
            <xsl:variable name="newid" select="substring-after($occid,'#')"/>
                <xsl:call-template name="createCL">
                <xsl:with-param name="occStr" select="$newid"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
                <xsl:call-template name="createCL">
                <xsl:with-param name="occStr" select="substring-after($occStr,' ')"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
<!-- inside createCL otherwise occStr <xsl:value-of select="$occStr"/> -->      
        <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:choose>
         <xsl:when test="contains($occStr,'#')">
            <xsl:variable name="newid" select="substring-after($occStr,'#')"/>
<!-- 
         Calling the creCLext template , passing parameter occid as newid variable
-->
                <xsl:call-template name="creCLext">
                <xsl:with-param name="occid" select="$newid"/>
            </xsl:call-template>                
         </xsl:when>
             <xsl:otherwise>
<!-- 
         Calling the creCLext template , passing parameter occid as occStr variable
-->
                <xsl:call-template name="creCLext">
                    <xsl:with-param name="occid" select="$occStr"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

<!-- Defining creCLext template -->
<xsl:template name="creCLext">
<xsl:param name="occid"/>

<!-- Reference to the user element and user_id,status and license_level attribute  -->

    <xsl:variable name="user" select="/plm:PLMXML/plm:User[@id=$occid]"/>
    <xsl:variable name="per_ref" select="substring-after($user/@personRef,'#')" />
    <xsl:variable name="user_id" select="$user/@userId" />
    <xsl:variable name="license_level" select="$user/plm:UserData/plm:UserValue[3]/@value"/>
    <xsl:variable name="last_login_time" select="$user/plm:UserData/plm:UserValue[4]/@value"/>

<!-- Reference to the person element and last name attribute  -->

    <xsl:variable name="person" select="/plm:PLMXML/plm:Person[@id=$per_ref]"/>         
    <xsl:variable name="person_l" select="$person/@lastName"/>


   <!-- Displaying the values by row order -->
      <tr>
         <td>
         <xsl:value-of select="$person_l"/></td>
         <td><xsl:value-of select="$user_id"/></td>
         <td><xsl:choose>
              <xsl:when test="$license_level=0">Author</xsl:when> <!-- Converting the output to string value -->
              <xsl:otherwise>Consumer</xsl:otherwise>
             </xsl:choose>
         </td>
         <td><xsl:value-of select="$last_login_time"/></td>
      </tr>           
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: The basic problem of this code is that it doesn't use unnamed templates and, correspondingly, `<xsl:apply-templates>` -- the described "problem" is a very simple one that when templates are appropriately used, doesn't need even sorting. I strongly recommend that you read a good book on XSLT and XPath and at least grasp the essentials before starting to write any XSLT transformation. XSLT is not like C or Java, or C#, or any language that you have used so far -- it requires "paradigm shift" and you obviously haven't passed that point.

Comment: Thanks @DimitreNovatchev , Yeh i am a newbie to XSLT and just meeting an small transformation requirement . I am almost done with it and i need to sort out before it is displayed . Is it possible to sort the elements the way they are without undergoing major changes in xslt code ?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [xsl:sort](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/el_sort.asp). Here is a pretty good [example](http://www.johnvey.com/features/deliciousdirector/xslt-filter-sort.html) how to use it.

Comment: Thanks @werner but I have read it already , it states that we can use sort always within <xsl:for-each> or <xsl:apply-templates>.Whereas i want to sort inside <xsl:choose>

Comment: Without seeing your XML source it's hard to explain where the sort should go. Somewhere in your source document there will be a set of elements that you want sorted. Somewhere in your stylesheet there will be an xsl:for-each or xsl:apply-templates that processes that set of elements. That xsl:for-each or xsl:apply-templates is where the xsl:sort needs to go.

Comment: @michealkay , I have attached the xslt code above . The xsl:for-each and xsl:apply-templates are not being used as the function is being called repetitively . Can i sort the license_status as it is being displayed ?